# How to group by the same key in a collection

Tags: javascript, lodash

Assume the following objects

```js
let oldArr = [
  { a: 1 },
  { a: 2 },
  { a: 3 },
  { b: 1 },
  { b: 2 },
  { c: 1 }
]
```

Desired result

```js
let newArr = [
  [
    { a: 1 },
    { a: 2 },
    { a: 3 },
  ],
  [
    { b: 1 },
    { b: 2 },
  ],
  [
    { c: 1 }
  ],
]
```

I try to use lodash, I see the ***partition*** function but it only splits the arrays into 2 groups. The ***groupBy*** groups it into an object by keys.
Is there any good way? hope to get everyone's help, thank you!

Comment: `Object.values(_.groupBy(oldArr))`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to group an array of objects by key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40774697/how-to-group-an-array-of-objects-by-key)

Comment: _.groupBy(oldArr, ele => { return Object.keys(ele)[0]})
Result: 

{a:[{a:1},{a:2},{a:3}],b:[{b:1},{b:2}],c:[{c:1}]}

Underscore.js

Comment: Thanks everyone, Your answer does not solve my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this using [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) and [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
let oldArr = [
  { a: 1 },
  { a: 2 },
  { a: 3 },
  { b: 1 },
  { b: 2 },
  { c: 1 },
  { a: 4, c: 2 }
]

let newArr = 
  // drop the keys of the object created by the reduce
  Object.values(
    // for each object in the array
    oldArr.reduce((acc, el) => {
      // for each keys in the object
      Object.keys(el).forEach(key => {
        // add the object to the group of objects with this key
        acc[key] = acc[key] || []
        acc[key].push(el)
      })
      return acc
    }, {})
  )

console.log(newArr)
```

if an object in the input have multiple keys it will go to each group in the output

Answer (score 0):

Simply like this:

```js
let oldArr = [
  { a: 1 },
  { a: 2 },
  { a: 3 },
  { b: 1 },
  { b: 2 },
  { c: 1 }
]

let objects = {};

for (let item of oldArr) {
  // get key
  let key = Object.keys(item)[0];
  // check if this key added before
  if (!objects[key]) objects[key] = [];
  // push this object
  objects[key].push(item);
}

let newArr = Object.values(objects);

console.log(newArr)
```

But you should be sure that every object in `oldArr` has only one key.

Comment: [How do I create a runnable stack snippet?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992)

Answer (score 0):

you can use like that

```js
let oldArr = [
  { a: 1 },
  { a: 2 },
  { a: 3 },
  { b: 1 },
  { b: 2 },
  { c: 1 }
];
let newArr = {};
oldArr.forEach((i)=>{
  let key = Object.keys(i)[0];
  newArr[key] = newArr[key] || [];
  newArr[key].push(i);
});
newArr = Object.values(newArr);
console.log(newArr);
```